# WebGL cuts part of the 3D image (works fine in RGL viewer)

Tags: r, webgl, rgl

I am trying to export a 3D plot from the `plot3D()` function as so:

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)
srtm <- getData("SRTM", lon=-15.59972, lat=27.965)

library(rgdal)
library(rasterVis)
library(rgl)
library(htmlwidgets)

open3d() # Open a new RGL device
plot3D(srtm)
```

When I run the code in R, everything works fine. The plot is rendered correctly in the RGL device window.

However, when I want to either export to html or embed it in a RMarkdown, part of the 3D plot gets cut.

By following the link below, you can see the html from

```
writeWebGL(dir = "webGL", filename = file.path(getwd(), "index.html"), width = 1000, height = 1000)
```

or

```
browseURL(paste("file://", writeWebGL(dir=file.path(getwd(), "webGL"), width=1000), sep=""))
```

[html from writeWebGL](https://github.com/ShirinG/blog_posts_prep/blob/master/GranCanaria/index.html)

I also tried the following to embed the plot in an RMarkdown:

```
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
options(rgl.printRglwidget = TRUE)

open3d()
plot3D(srtm)
rglscene <- scene3d()
# render the saved rgl scene as widget in the markdown page
rglwidget(rglscene,webGLoptions = list(preserveDrawingBuffer = FALSE))
```

[Here is the RMarkdown that got produced](https://github.com/ShirinG/blog_posts_prep/blob/master/GranCanaria/webgl.html)

Does somebody know why the plot gets cut in the html? I see the same if I plot other countries, btw. Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll need to post a reproducible example.  We can't see what you see in R, and we can't debug based only on the WebGL output.

Comment: 7.59 MB of html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs say in `?writeWebGL`, there's a limit of 65536 vertices in objects in WebGL in many browsers.  Your surface object is 316 by 316, which gives it about 100000 vertices.  You'll need to break it up into two or more pieces, or plot it with lower resolution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I lowered maxpixels in plot3D(), that did the trick.